# What do I need to do to get php to be able to send mail with Google Apps?

Tags: php, email, sendmail, postfix-mta, mx-record

Currently there are no MX records pointing to my server. Will I need to change any MX records to get php sendmail working? I only need php to be able to send mail (on multiple virtual domains...). Also do you recommend sendmail or postfix? thanks...

Comment: I don't think you need to change anything, Google MX server is `ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM` if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postfix is much easier to configure, so I say Postfix any day.

You won't have to change any MX records just to send mail. Just configure Postfix properly and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a library the allows you to send from a remote SMTP server. Typically i use SwiftMailer but in the past phpMailer has done the job just fine...

Comment: o.O you hurt my brain. err... :p I just need php to be able to send with project pier and other web apps... concrete5, cscart... anyway...

Comment: so... I just configure each of my web apps to send through Google's SMTP servers?

Comment: Well yes but if you are using applications you didnt build then you would have to make modification to make them send with one of these libraries instead of the native mail function. That said i woudl check the docs... a lot of apps are going to support using an external SMTP server, often times using one of the two libraries i mentioned... Check the documentation for the apps in question.